# Using FileHelpers how can I ignore RelationshipManager field?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I! I'm working in a c# wpf application. I'm using FileHelpers to export data to csv files. I'm using too .net entity framework, so this framework already has classes of my sql server database. 
For export data Filehelpers says this:

```
    SqlServerStorage storage = new SqlServerStorage(typeof(OrdersVerticalBar));

       storage.ServerName = "NEON-64";
       storage.DatabaseName = "Northwind";

       // Comment this for Windows Auth
       storage.UserName = "Marcos";
       storage.UserPass = "private :)";
storage.FillRecordCallback = new FillRecordHandler(FillRecordOrder);  

   OrdersVerticalBar[] res = storage.ExtractRecords() as OrdersVerticalBar[];
```

"OrdersVerticalBar" is my class

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class OrdersVerticalBar
{
    public int OrderID;
    public string CustomerID;
    public int EmployeeID; 
    public DateTime OrderDate;
    public DateTime RequiredDate;

    [FieldNullValue(typeof(DateTime), "2005-1-1")]
    public DateTime ShippedDate; 
    public int ShipVia; 
    public decimal Freight;
}
```

This is method to get data:

```
protected void FillRecordOrder(object rec, object[] fields)
{
    OrdersVerticalBar record = (OrdersVerticalBar) rec;

    record.OrderID = (int) fields[0];
    record.CustomerID = (string) fields[1];
    record.EmployeeID = (int) fields[2];
    record.OrderDate = (DateTime) fields[3];
    record.RequiredDate = (DateTime) fields[4];

    if (fields[5] != DBNull.Value)
         record.ShippedDate = (DateTime) fields[5];
    else
         record.ShippedDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    record.ShipVia = (int) fields[6];
    record.Freight = (decimal) fields[7];
}
```

It says I've to create this class, but entity framework already create it.
So, when I try to get data I get "BadUsageException":

> The field: '_relationships' has the type: RelationshipManager that is
>   not a system type, so this field need a CustomConverter ( Please Check
>   the docs for more Info).

I try to convert field "_relationship" type RelationShipManager or to ignore it, but dont work.
How can I resolve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the field to be ignored or removed under the Engine.Options, see http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/DynamicChangeOptions/